# How to prevent outside scrolling when using fancybox with ajax content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using [fancyBox](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox) to load Ajax content as:

```
<a href="/example.html" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax">Example</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>
```

The documentation says that you can prevent outside scrolling if you set:

```
scrollOutside = false
```

But this does not work when loading ajax content.

How can I prevent that the scrolling outside of the fancyBox does not appear when the fancyBox is visible?

Comment: It should do it by default, unless you set `overflow` css properties to either the `html` or `body` tags.

Comment: i am having the same issue, could you fix it ?

Comment: The author of the plugin wrote that helpers : { overlay:{ locked: true } } will work but it does not work for me. How can I make it work?

Comment: @RULE101 does locked: true works for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        scrollOutside: false
    });
});
```

Comment: I wrote above that this does not work. Any other idea? This is just for the fancybox content.